# How do I structure my React app?

Tags: reactjs

Right now I have 5 search inputs on the frontend, each searching for something different.

I only have an App component, and right now 5 different boxes for displaying search results. How should I go about dividing this up so only a single search result box is displayed (the one that was searched for)?

I have 5 of the following code:

```
       <div className='searchBox'>
          <div class='searchTitle'>Search for a Planet</div>
          <div class='searchInput'>
            <input type='text' value={this.state.planetName} onChange={this.handlePlanetNameChange.bind(this)} placeholder='Enter planet name'></input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Results for Person</h1>
    <table id='Person'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Height</th>
          <th>Mass</th>
          <th>Hair color</th>
          <th>Skin color</th>
          <th>Eye color</th>
          <th>Birth year</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Homeworld</th>
          <th>Films</th>
          <th>Species</th>
          <th>Vehicles</th>
          <th>Starships</th>
          <th>Url</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th>Edited</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

{
this.state.personData.results.map(result => (
<tr>
  <td>{result.name.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.height.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.mass.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.hair_color.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.skin_color.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.eye_color.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.birth_year.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.gender.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.homeworld.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.films.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.species.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.vehicles.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.starships.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.url.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.created.toString()}</td>
  <td>{result.edited.toString()}</td>
</tr>
```

))
   }

Comment: Add the relevant code and I'll be happy to assist. Right now your question is too vague for anybody to answer properly...

Comment: Just added code

Comment: Great! Though I can only see 1 input box, not 5?

Comment: all of them have the same implementation, just with different names